# To match all characters not ending with specified string

Tags: regex

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | grep -onP  '\w+(?!abc\b)'
1:xxabc
1:jkl
```

Why the result is not as below?

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | grep -onP  '\w+(?!abc\b)'
1:jkl
```

The first string is `xxabc` which ending with abc.
I want to extract all  characters  which not ending with abc,why `xxabc` matched?
How to fix it,that is to say get only `1:jkl` as output?
Why '\w+(?!abc\b)'  can't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`\w+(?!abc\b)` pattern matches `xxabc`](https://regex101.com/r/y7y3oW/2) because `\w+` matches 1 or more word chars greedily, and thus grabs `xxabc` at once. Then, the negative lookahead `(?!abc\b)` makes sure there is no `abc` with a trailing word boundary immediately to the left of the current location. Since after `xxabc` there is no `abc` with a trailing word boundary, the match *succeeds*.

To match all words that do not end with `abc` using a PCRE regex, you may use

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | grep -onP  '\b\w+\b(?<!abc)'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Up9V7X)

**Details**

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary
- `(?<!abc)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if the 3 letters immediately to the left of the current location are `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

Without pcregrep special features, you can do it adding a pipe to sed:

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]*abc//g' | grep -onE '[a-zA-Z]+'
```

or with awk:

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | awk -F'[^a-zA-Z]+' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if ($i!~/abc$/) printf "%s: %s\n",NR,$i }}'
```

other approach:

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | awk -F'([^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]*abc\\>)+' '{OFS="\n"NR": ";if ($1) printf OFS;$1=$1}1'
```